# Why x86 JIT is smarter than x64?

Tags: c#, .net, assembly, il, .net-4.5.2

I'm running a very simple program

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Get4S());
        Console.WriteLine(Get4());
    }

    private static int Get4S()
    {
        return 4;
    }

    private static int Get4()
    {
        int res = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            res++;
        }
        return res;
    }
```

when it works under `x86` it inlines `Get4S` method and `Get4` asm code is:

```
00000000  push        ebp 
00000001  mov         ebp,esp 
00000003  xor         eax,eax 
00000005  inc         eax 
00000006  inc         eax 
00000007  inc         eax 
00000008  inc         eax 
00000009  pop         ebp 
0000000a  ret
```

BUT when running under x64 we get same asm for `Get4S` method, but `Get4` asm is not optimized at all:

```
00000000  xor         eax,eax 
00000002  xor         edx,edx 
00000004  inc         eax 
00000006  inc         edx 
00000008  cmp         edx,4 
0000000b  jl          0000000000000004 
0000000d  ret
```

I supposed that `x64` JIT unroll the loop, then see that result can be computed in compile-time, and function with compile-time result will be inlined. But nothing from it happend.

Why `x64` is so stupid in this case?..

Comment: Are jit opimizations enabled?

Comment: @CodesInChaos of course, you see that x86 code is optimised. It's not optimal, but it unrolled the loop, it's impossible when jit optimisations are suppressed.

Comment: Could not reproduce. x64 JIT also optimized to the constant 4 for me. Code looked like this: http://pastebin.com/UEtXUsLA

Comment: I'd suspect that the x64 jitter didnt receive much love/attention back in the early days of .NET as its was the exception rather than the rule back then. As this trend has changed some of those limitations are more apparent and Microsoft are addressing it with RyuJIT (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/09/30/ryujit-the-next-generation-jit-compiler.aspx)

Comment: @neil In my tests the old x64 optimizer produced faster code than ryujit.

Comment: @neildanson I was talking with MVP one week ago, and he had multiple proofs that x64 JIT is much smarter than ruyjit, which also is so back-compatible that it has even all x86 JIT bugs. For example see "first-instruction-starg-bug" (`DevDiv Bugs 81184`). This is why I was surprised by this behaviour

Comment: x64 actually also inlines `Get4` as 4 (not shown in the code I posted earlier because the way I got that code precludes inlining the function). So it's much better than the x86 JIT (as usual)

Comment: @harold in this case I don't understand why it didn't optimize it on my machine. Do you have same output for your x86?

Comment: I have the same output for x86 (that output is really quite silly, it unrolled 4 increments and didn't even notice? no peephole optimizer??), so, what procedure do you follow to get this output?

Comment: Breakpoints on two returns. First breakpoint is now working, but it's espected because of inlining. But second breaks. And it's bizzare but it breaks on `i < 4` condition when I set breakpoint on return (see screenshot http://take.ms/HrF9a ). I also found that x64 compilation is much slower: ~15 seconds against 1sec for x86.

Comment: It gets confused about the location of breakpoints in optimized code sometimes (actually a lot). How do you even get it to break at a breakpoint at all though?

Comment: @harold excuse? Also I mean `First breakpoint is not working, but it's expected`, a little typing mistake

Comment: Well, you unchecked the box "Suppress JIT optimizations", right? If I do that, your second breakpoint does not work for me either

Comment: @harold yes, weird behaviour... Unfortunly, I don't know source of this issue and solution for it... It seems to be an environment problem.

Comment: @CodesInChaos 
Interesting - I havent tried RyuJit in over a year - I didnt find any huge difference in my code, so wasnt worth the hassle, but the idea of a free speedup was nice :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the point. It's because RyuJIT is used when `x64` build is selected, even if `.Net 4.5.2` target platform is selected. So i fixed it by adding this section in App.Config file:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <useLegacyJit enabled="1" />
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

This markup enables "legacy" x64 JIT (in quotes, because I think he's much better than "shiny" RyuJIT), and result ASM in main method is:

```
00000000  sub         rsp,28h 
00000004  mov         ecx,4 
00000009  call        000000005EE75870 
0000000e  mov         ecx,4 
00000013  call        000000005EE75870 
00000018  nop 
00000019  add         rsp,28h 
0000001d  ret
```

both methods was calculated in compile time and inlined by theirs values.

Conclusion: When `.Net 4.6` is installed, old x64 jitter is replaced by `RyuJIT` for all solutions under `CLR4.0`. So only way to turn it off is `useLegacyJit` switch or `COMPLUS_AltJit` environment variable

Comment: *because I think he's much better than "shiny" RyuJIT* Battle hardened JIT works better than the unsupported pre-release version: news at 11.

Comment: @ta.speot.is I'm not saying that RyuJIT should never born, I'm saying that Microsoft says "everybody, we have a new uberfast JITter, you'l like it", but it's not true for now. In future - maybe. Anyway, I don't see any reason why they decided to base RyuJIT on x86 jitter, when x64 was smarter in all ways (except this rare bug with wry loop unrolling).