# x86 version starts faster than x64/Any CPU

Tags: c#, wpf, performance

Some time ago I noticed that my release version of my application starts 2 times slower than the debug version (10-12 seconds for release and 4-5 for debug). That was because I set platform target to **Any CPU** for release build and **x86** for Debug build. When I change release configuration to x86 then both versions need the same time to start.

I don't understand why setting platform to Any CPU or x64 so much slows application startup.

In my application I am using following libraries:

- EF6
- Log4Net
- Fody
- Autofac
- DevExpress WPF controls

Maybe one of used libraries slows my application startup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.NET has currently (pre-4.6) different JIT engines for x86 and x64 platforms and they have different startup times. In 4.6 the engines will be more similar and the startup time should be less different.

You can already test with 4.6 pre-version if this is the cause.

Some discussion about this also at https://stackoverflow.com/a/29595194/1806780

Comment: Yeah, I understand that JIT works only for the first application startup - need to compile CIL to machine code. So when I run second time, third etc. the application startup should not depend on JIT. Am I right here?

Comment: @rraszewski It depends on JIT every time. JIT doesn't cache any code between startups, only while the application is running. If you want to keep the native code, you'd have to use ngen.

Comment: OK, I'll check 4.6 JIT compiler. But what about different types of jit compilation?
 http://www.telerik.com/blogs/understanding-net-just-in-time-compilation
Any comment on that?