# Why my application working to slow, is it any code to make this application going faster?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2012

I'm making a application to find if the value of data grid is any in the table 1 after that do update on the table 2 data grid fill is table 2 my code is working but it's need 1 minutes or more to have done 1 row, is there any code to make my application working faster?

this is my code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim sql As String = "select date,npk,nama,masuk,out,h_ot,flag,status from lemburapril"
    Dim dataadapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, str)
    str.Open()
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    dataadapter.Fill(ds, "ds")
    str.Close()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
    DataGridView1.DataMember = "ds"
    For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1

        Dim tgl As Date = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0).ToString
        Dim npk As String = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(1).ToString
        Dim nama As String = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(2).ToString
        Dim masuk As String = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(3).ToString
        Dim out As String = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(4).ToString
        Dim h_ot As String = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(5).ToString
        Dim Flag As String = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(6).ToString
        Dim status As String = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(7).ToString
        For Each Rows In DataGridView1.Rows
            Dim sqlup As String = "update lemburapril set status = 'v' where date = any (select date from ABY1904$ where date ='" & tgl & "') and npk = any (select npk from ABY1904$ where npk = '" & npk & "')"
            str.Open()
            COMMANDSQL(sqlup)
            str.Close()
        Next
    Next
End Sub
Public Sub display()
    Dim sql As String = "select date,npk,nama,masuk,out,h_ot,flag,status from lemburapril"
    Dim dataadapter As New SqlDataAdapter(Sql, str)
    str.Open()
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    dataadapter.Fill(ds, "ds")
    str.Close()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
    DataGridView1.DataMember = "ds"
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    display()
End Sub
End Class
```

This is my connection :

```
Module koneksi
Dim sqlcom As New SqlCommand
Dim commansql As String

Public str As New SqlConnection("data source= Somebody-PC\SQLEXPRESS ;initial catalog= lembur ;integrated security =true")
Public Sub COMMANDSQL(ByVal S As String)
    sqlcom = New SqlCommand(S, str)
    sqlcom.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: One possible reason for slow apps is build configuration as explained here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30952422/x86-version-starts-faster-than-x64-any-cpu

Comment: Never store and try to re-use a Connection. It will kill your application. Create, use and dispose of it in-place. Btw, using a DataAdapter, it will open the connection for you.

Comment: you need to find out either your SQL query is taking that much time or your code behind logic is making it slow. run you SQL query in management studio and check, if that is taking time then create indexes & look for other DB optimization. for bulk update there are many other speedy ways to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the module. Keep all your database objects local so you can close and dispose them. Using...End Using blocks take care of this even if there is an error. It looks like you were looping through all the rows and running the update again for each row in the nested for. That gives you n*n which would slow things down.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    display()
End Sub

Private ConnString As String = "data source= Somebody-PC\SQLEXPRESS ;initial catalog= lembur ;integrated security =true"

Private dt As New DataTable

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Using Str As New SqlConnection(ConnString)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Update lemburapril Set status = 'v' Where date = any (Select date From ABY1904$ Where date =@tgl) And npk = any (Select npk From ABY1904$ Where npk = @npk)", Str)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@tgl", SqlDbType.Date)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@npk", SqlDbType.VarChar)
            Str.Open()
            For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                cmd.Parameters("@tgl").Value = CDate(dt.Rows(i).Item(0))
                cmd.Parameters("@npk").Value = dt.Rows(i).Item(1).ToString
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
Public Sub display()
    Using Str As New SqlConnection(ConnString)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("select date,npk,nama,masuk,[out],h_ot,flag,status from lemburapril", Str)
            Str.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```